# jQuery Effects in PHP While Loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Ok I have a list of featured paintings to show on the Index.
I am displaying them using a while loop to get the details from the database.

I want to create a jQuery effect for when the user hovers over the image, the div of that picture appears.

The problem is is that if i were to hover on the first one, the first one's div is ok, but if i were to hover and leave the second one, it would affect the first one. Code below:

Script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featuredImage img").hover(function(){
    $("#details").fadeOut();
   });
  });
</script>
```

PHP While

```
<ul id="featured">
 <?php
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM paintings WHERE featured=1");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $name = $row['name'];
     $desc = $row['longDesc'];
     $cost = $row['cost'];
     $qty = $row['quantity'];
     $img = $row['imageFilename'];
     $type = $row['type'];
     echo "
      <li id='featuredImage'>
      <div id='featuredImage'><div id='details'>$name</div><img src='/$img'></div>
      </li>";
    }
 ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1. `id`s are unique across the whole document; 2. you don't need js for that, CSS is enough.

Comment: No. I want the animation for the width enlaregment

Comment: That's what CSS transitions are for.

Comment: css transitions dont work in 30% of all browsers. http://caniuse.com/css-transitions so its not really recommended for real production, unless you dont care the 20%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".featuredImage img").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".imgDetails").fadeOut();
   });
  });
```

ID's are meant to be unique, use classes instead to match my code above... something like this:

```
  <li class='imageWrap'>
  <div class='featuredImage'><div class='imgDetails'>$name</div><img src='/$img'></div>
  </li>
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/UHXqd/

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do is easy to achieve: 
Basically change `$("#details").fadeOut();` to `$(this).siblings("#details").fadeOut();`.
But there are other things wrong with your code too:
You have multiple domElements with the same ID, what is quite unfortunate, IDs should be unique.
My advice: change the echo to

```
<li class='imageContainer'>
  <div class='featuredImage'><div class='details'>$name</div><img src='/$img'></div>
</li>
```

And from here on dont use the '#' in the selectors, use the '.' to select classes, not ids.

```
$(".featuredImage img").hover(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".details").fadeOut();
});
```

You should use siblings() because the details-div is on the same level as the image.